# How does a websocket know the server was taken down?

Tags: http, networking, browser, tcp, websocket

I was playing with websocket a bit (using Sails.js with its built-in socket thing, which is based on Socket.io).

I noticed Chrome receives two frames every 25 seconds. I thought this was some kind of polling to tell the connection was still on.

But then, I cancelled the server and Chrome was notified immediately.

Also I closed the Node process by force with the `kill` command, and still Chrome was notified, so that means it wasn't Node sending a signal before shutting down the server.

How does this happen?

Comment: The connection was either closed with a FIN or reset with an RST by the peer operating system when the peer process exited, which in turn caused either end of stream or a 'connection reset' on the local socket.

Answer (score 4):

Normal TCP socket connections do this, so it'd be surprising if websockets *didn't*.

The server kernel is responsible for cleaning up when the server process dies/exits/is killed. This includes releasing memory, closing files, and shutting down sockets. Cleanly shutting down a TCP socket requires sending a message to tell the peer.

Interestingly, on some old versions of Windows with userspace winsock, this didn't happen if the server process crashed. On all OS with compliant TCP support, it should be guaranteed unless the kernel itself hangs, the machine loses power, or the network breaks.

Comment: Cleanly shutting down a TCP socket requires sending a *FIN* message to the peer. RST is an *abortive* close.

Comment: Nice, so if the internet connection is abruptly completely cut off from the server (without any time to tell the client), the client wouldn't be able to tell immediately the connection broke?

Comment: @EJP yeah, I deliberately avoid mentioning `FIN` and `RST` because it feels like more detail than OP wanted, and it's trivial to look up the details once you know what's happening.

Comment: @FeloVilches yep, if you just pull the network cable from the server, the client won't find out it's gone until it tries to send something (eg, a poll request), and the TCP layer waits until that times out, and then retries a few times ... it can take a while before the client OS decides the connection is definitely dead and tells the client process.

Comment: @EJP using `RST` **is** a form of clean shutdown since it follows the TCP/IP protocol requirements. It cleanly informs the client that the connection was aborted and reset by the host. Don't over-lawyer the answers. this isn;'t the `man` page, this is a helping hand pointing towards the general direction.

Comment: @Myst No. RST is an abortive close. FIN is a clean shutdown. Anything else that doesn't comply to the TCP protocol isn't a shutdown at all. Who exactly is over-lawyering here?

Comment: @EJP - How is an abortive close not clean? Unplugging the cable, now there's a dirty trick, but `RST`? ... Anyway, I think the answer was correct enough, even if it might have been less accurate than it could have been. I up voted it and I have no idea why it would be down voted.

Comment: @Myst How is an abortive close not abortive? And how is a protocol error any kind of a close? TCP will just throw it away. And how is unplugging the cable a close? TCP will just time it out, *and then issue a reset*. The answer *is* correct enough now that he's removed the part about the reset.

Comment: @EJP I guess you made me review [the TCP/IP RFC's definition of CLOSE](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793#section-3.5): *CLOSE is an operation meaning "I have no more data to send."* ... I do feel that RST fits the definition, but, as stated in the RFC: *The notion of closing a full-duplex connection is subject to ambiguous interpretation* ... so I guess we might both be right.

Comment: @EJP I feel like this answer addresses the question at the appropriate level of detail, but I'm sure it's not perfect, and reasonable people can easily disagree on both the wording and the level it's pitched at. You should definitely write your own answer if you think it'd be better!

Comment: @Myst The *very section you quoted* states *clearly and unambiguously* that CLOSE sends a FIN. Read on.

Comment: @Useless I don't have any problem with your answer since you removed the 'reset'. It's a good answer.

Comment: @EJP I guess we'll have a friendly disagreement. I read the section to state that FIN closes the connection while listening for incoming data, and RST closes the connection without accepting incoming data (no more data to send + no read). Besides, the section regarding RST clearly stated the connection's state is changed to CLOSE, indicating it's a closure. I do understand your point of view, but I guess I read it differently. I think that's okay. Some variation in interpretation is what makes this world so much fun :-)

Comment: @Myst I guess you just can't read the RFC. The section you are quoting doesn't say any such thing. It doesn't mention RST **at all.** It supports what I have been telling you *in toto*. The connection state is changed to `CLOSED', which isn't the same thing as 'CLOSE'.

Comment: @EJP , it's okay, I don't mind that you hold your opinion. I do request that you respect my right to have a different one. I think it's unkind to claim that the "*The section you are quoting doesn't say any such thing*" when I was referencing the RFC as a whole. Sections such as the one explaining about [half-open connections](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793#page-33) and the paragraph I referenced regarding [connection resets](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793#page-37) were also considered. **It's okay that you think I'm misinterpreting, it's *not* okay to claim I'm illiterate.**

Comment: @EJP - P.S. you're as stubborn as I am, I love that. Keep rocking.

Comment: @Myst It's not opinion, it's fact. Graceful and abortive close. FIN and RST. No other kind of close. It's all in the RFC you keep misquoting. You didn't say the 'entire RFC', you *specifically said* 'I read the section ...'. So you are even misquoting yourself. I didn't say anything about 'illiterate', and it is not OK to put words into my mouth. What I said was 'can't read the RFC', and the evidence above supports it.

Comment: @EJP   you win!  ☺️